# Makefile process several files

Tags: makefile

I want to parse several json files, get their contents, prepend/append some text and save the new string in another file. Currently I have this which works for a single file:

```
#set variables for shared libs
SHAREDFILE=$(SERVERPATH)/xx/mod/supervisor/cfg/prod/config.json
JSONCONF = `cat "$(SHAREDFILE)"`

share:
    @echo "Sharing node-client code in ${PROJECT}.- ENV $(ENV)..."
    @echo "parseConfig($(JSONCONF));" > $(CLIENTPATH)/public/js/shared/config.json
```

Since from what i understand variables can only be set outside rules how would i go about doing this for a list of files?

Update: the files to be copied can be in separate directories but they should all be copied to the same target directory.

Comment: It would help if you gave more than one example. Do you mean a list (`config.json`, `some.json`, `other.json`) of files to be found in `$(SERVERPATH)/xx/mod/supervisor/cfg/prod/` and to be modified and saved in `$(CLIENTPATH)/public/js/shared/`?

Comment: Yes @Beta, except not all files are in the same source directory, but they do all end up in the same target directory

Answer (score 2):

Based on a guess about your list of files:

```
SHAREDFILES = foo.json bar.json baz.json

TARGETS = $(addprefix $(CLIENTPATH)/public/js/shared/, $(SHAREDFILES))

share: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS) : $(CLIENTPATH)/public/js/shared/%.json : $(SERVERPATH)/xx/mod/supervisor/cfg/prod/%.json
    @echo "Sharing node-client code in ${PROJECT}.- ENV $(ENV)..."
    @echo "parseConfig(`cat $<`);" > $@
```

**EDIT:**
If the source files are in several directories, but the targets all go into the same directory... There are several ways to do it. This is probably the best:

```
SHAREDFILES = some/path/foo.json another/path/bar.json yet/another/path/baz.json

TARGETDIR = $(CLIENTPATH)/public/js/shared
TARGETS = $(addprefix $(TARGETDIR)/, $(notdir $(SHAREDFILES)))

vpath %.json $(dir $(SHAREDFILES))

share: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS) : $(TARGETDIR)/%.json : %.json
    @echo "Sharing node-client code in ${PROJECT}.- ENV $(ENV)..."
    @echo "parseConfig(`cat $<`);" > $@
```

Comment: How about when the files are in separate directories? eg, I have a list of absolute paths to files in SHAREDFILES, how could it be done?